# Is there any way to pipe request body only in express?

Tags: node.js, express

In my project there are 2 web servers, one is nodejs to serving the requests from frontend (authentication, acl control, ...), while another one is a Java stateless sever for the real work.

The nodejs server needs to foward a file upload (multipart/form-data) request to the backend java server. I'm trying to pipe the raw uploaded file data by `request` module.

```js
app.post('/file/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  req.pipe(request.post('http://java-server/file/upload', function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.json(body);
  }));
});
```

The question is I'm piping the whole request (including headers) instead of just body data. I can't find any method to get something like `req.body.stream()` so I can directly pipe the uploaded file.

This way I can't insert additional headers such as `Authorization` which are required by the java server.

Anyone helps? Thanks.